# Using SharedPreferences to save an ArrayList of Subclasses of an Abstract Class

Tags: java, android, abstract-class, parcelable

Good afternoon everyone, I'am university studentand I decided to to make a clicker game for fun and it was going really well until now because I came across a "bug" I can't understand:

I have an Abstract class called "UpgradesClick" which has all the Click Upgrades inside, as follows: [Abstract Class Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0ph8.png)

 My Abstract Class "UpgradesClick" implements Parcelable ( I tried passing it through an Intent.PutExtra and it didn't work) [Abstract Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyFnU.png)

Then I thought SharedPreferences would save me, because I had already heard of them, and i want my Upgrade Click store activity to do a save() onPause() [Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4J7D.png) call, to save all of the object's values, the Level and the Price so i decided to make an ArrayList of the Abstract Class UpgradeClick and all of them inside. [Adding objects to ArrayList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2wlz.png)

Then I wrote the typical SharedPreferences calls Save() and Load() and whenever I move from the MainActivity to the Store, it displays that the data has been loaded(1)* but when i move back to the MainActivity the game crashes, and sets all my values back to 0(2)*  [--- *see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OH1r.jpg)

And here's my problem, I get an error on my onSave() method that I can't understand, for it dosen't underline anything. [Save() and Load() methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhIef.png)

It gives me an error on the "json = gson.toJson(todosUpgradesClick);" which I assume its where I convert the ArrayList into a Json file.

Really sad that this thing of "sending objects to other Activities" is not allowing me to continue my game, because most of the game code is just adding the value of each Class and multiplying by others on my onClick method.

Also sorry for not posting any code on the post, but it was so big I tought no one would be bothered to read. Thank you very much for you time dear stack overflowers ;)

PS: In case you're wondering about the "List", I had it to be an ArrayList first, but it didn't work, so the screenshot part where it says "List" was also tried as an ArrayList.

And once again, thank you for your time and patience.

Edit - Added code and error log

Code:

```
> 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public abstract class UpgradesClick extends MainActivity implements Parcelable {
    private int nivel;
    private int preco;
    private int precoBase;
    private int valorGanhoPorClick;
    Activity act;

    //private TextView tvQtdPClick;
    private TextView tvnivel;
    private TextView tvpreco;

    protected UpgradesClick(Activity act, int nivel, int precoBase){
        //setTvQtdPClick( (TextView) act.findViewById(R.id.qtdcuspopc) );
        this.nivel = nivel;
        this.precoBase = precoBase;
        this.act = act;
    }
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(nivel);
        out.writeInt(preco);
    }
    protected UpgradesClick(Parcel in) {
        nivel = in.readInt();
        preco = in.readInt();
    }
    public void comprarUpgrade(){
        setNivel( getNivel() + 1 );
        setPreco( getNivel() * 5 );
        setValorGanhoPorClick( getNivel() );
    }
    public float getValorGanhoPorClick() {
        return valorGanhoPorClick;
    }
    public void setValorGanhoPorClick(int valorGanhoPorClick) {
        this.valorGanhoPorClick = valorGanhoPorClick;
    }
    public int getPrecoBase() {
        return precoBase;
    }
    public void setPrecoBase(int precoBase) {
        this.precoBase = precoBase;
    }
    public void setPreco(int preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }
    public int getPreco(){
        if (getNivel() == 0){
            return precoBase;
        }else {
            return preco;
        }
    }
    public int getNivel() {
        return nivel;
    }
    public void setNivel(int nivel) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }
    public void setTvnivel(TextView tvnivel) {
        this.tvnivel = tvnivel;
    }
    public TextView getTvnivel() {
        return tvnivel;
    }
    public void setTvpreco(TextView tvpreco) {
        this.tvpreco = tvpreco;
    }
    public TextView getTvpreco() {
        return tvpreco;
    }
}
class UpgradeClick_Gosma extends UpgradesClick{

    public UpgradeClick_Gosma(Activity act, int nivel, int precoBase) {

        super(act, nivel, precoBase);
        setValorGanhoPorClick(getNivel());
        setPreco(getPrecoBase() * getNivel());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Gosma> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Gosma>() {
        public UpgradeClick_Gosma createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Gosma(in);
        }

        @Override
        public UpgradeClick_Gosma[] newArray(int size) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Gosma[size];
        }
    };

    public UpgradeClick_Gosma(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
class UpgradeClick_Dedeta extends UpgradesClick{

    public UpgradeClick_Dedeta(Activity act, int nivel, int precoBase) {

        super(act, nivel, precoBase);
        setValorGanhoPorClick(getNivel());
        setPreco(getPrecoBase() * getNivel());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Dedeta> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Dedeta>() {
        public UpgradeClick_Dedeta createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Dedeta(in);
        }

        @Override
        public UpgradeClick_Dedeta[] newArray(int size) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Dedeta[size];
        }
    };

    public UpgradeClick_Dedeta(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
class UpgradeClick_Sorte extends UpgradesClick{

    public UpgradeClick_Sorte(Activity act, int nivel, int precoBase) {

        super(act, nivel, precoBase);
        setValorGanhoPorClick(getNivel());
        setPreco(getPrecoBase() * getNivel());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Sorte> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Sorte>() {
        public UpgradeClick_Sorte createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Sorte(in);
        }

        @Override
        public UpgradeClick_Sorte[] newArray(int size) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Sorte[size];
        }
    };

    public UpgradeClick_Sorte(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
class UpgradeClick_Douro extends UpgradesClick{

    public UpgradeClick_Douro(Activity act, int nivel, int precoBase) {

        super(act, nivel, precoBase);
        setValorGanhoPorClick(getNivel());
        setPreco(getPrecoBase() * getNivel());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Douro> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Douro>() {
        public UpgradeClick_Douro createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Douro(in);
        }

        @Override
        public UpgradeClick_Douro[] newArray(int size) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Douro[size];
        }
    };

    public UpgradeClick_Douro(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
class UpgradeClick_Agua extends UpgradesClick{

    public UpgradeClick_Agua(Activity act, int nivel, int precoBase) {

        super(act, nivel, precoBase);
        setValorGanhoPorClick(getNivel());
        setPreco(getPrecoBase() * getNivel());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Agua> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<UpgradeClick_Agua>() {
        public UpgradeClick_Agua createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Agua(in);
        }

        @Override
        public UpgradeClick_Agua[] newArray(int size) {
            return new UpgradeClick_Agua[size];
        }
    };

    public UpgradeClick_Agua(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

-- Code to shop activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UpgradeClickActvity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //UpgradesClick.UpgradeClick1 upgrade;

    Intent intent;

    int[] IMAGEM = {R.drawable.upgradespit1, R.drawable.upgradespit2, R.drawable.upgradespit3, R.drawable.upgradespit4, R.drawable.upgradespit5};
    int[] NOME = {R.string.UpgradeClick1Titulo, R.string.UpgradeClick2Titulo, R.string.UpgradeClick3Titulo, R.string.UpgradeClick4Titulo, R.string.UpgradeClick5Titulo};
    int[] DESCRICAO = {R.string.UpgradeClick1Descricao, R.string.UpgradeClick2Descricao, R.string.UpgradeClick3Descricao, R.string.UpgradeClick4Descricao, R.string.UpgradeClick5Descricao};


    UpgradeClick_Gosma upgradeclickgosma;
    UpgradeClick_Dedeta upgradeclickdedeta;
    UpgradeClick_Sorte upgradeclicksorte;
    UpgradeClick_Douro upgradeclickdouro;
    UpgradeClick_Agua upgradeclickagua;

    List<UpgradesClick> todosUpgradesClick;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.upgrades_click);
        todosUpgradesClick = new ArrayList<>();

        loadData();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Cuspo cuspo = (Cuspo) intent.getParcelableExtra("objCuspo");
        TextView textoQtdCuspo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lojaQtdCuspo);
        textoQtdCuspo.setText(String.valueOf(cuspo.getQtd()));
        TextView textoQtdCuspoUni = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lojaQtdCuspoUni);
        textoQtdCuspoUni.setText(String.valueOf(cuspo.getQtdUni()));


        upgradeclickgosma = new UpgradeClick_Gosma(this, 0, 20);
        upgradeclickdedeta = new UpgradeClick_Dedeta(this, 0, 100);
        upgradeclicksorte = new UpgradeClick_Sorte(this, 0, 500);
        upgradeclickdouro = new UpgradeClick_Douro(this, 0, 1000);
        upgradeclickagua = new UpgradeClick_Agua(this, 0, 5000);

        todosUpgradesClick.add(upgradeclickgosma);
        todosUpgradesClick.add(upgradeclickdedeta);
        todosUpgradesClick.add(upgradeclicksorte);
        todosUpgradesClick.add(upgradeclickdouro);
        todosUpgradesClick.add(upgradeclickagua);


        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewupgclick);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        ImageView btnBack = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnback) ;
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UpgradeClickActvity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("upggosma", upgradeclickgosma);
                //intent.putExtra("upgdedeta", upgradeclickdedeta);
                startActivity(intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveData();
        //intent = new Intent(UpgradeClickActvity.this, MainActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(UpgradeClickActvity.this, "Data saved" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return IMAGEM.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.upgradestemplate, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.template_imagem);
            TextView textView_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.template_titulo);
            TextView textView_descricao = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.template_descricao);
            TextView textView_preco = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.template_preco);
            TextView textView_nivel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.template_nivel);

            imageView.setImageResource(IMAGEM[position]);
            textView_name.setText(NOME[position]);
            textView_descricao.setText(DESCRICAO[position]);
            textView_preco.setText(String.valueOf(todosUpgradesClick.get(position).getPreco()));
            textView_nivel.setText(String.valueOf(todosUpgradesClick.get(position).getNivel()));

            return view;
        }
    }

    private void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(todosUpgradesClick);
        editor.putString("todosUpgradesClick", json);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void loadData(){
        Toast.makeText(UpgradeClickActvity.this, "Carregou dados" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("todosUpgradesClick", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<UpgradesClick>>() {}.getType();
        todosUpgradesClick = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        if(todosUpgradesClick == null){
            todosUpgradesClick = new ArrayList<UpgradesClick>();
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, the error log:

```
2018-10-30 21:34:44.470 1843-1963/? E/LogCollectService: illegal eventid
2018-10-30 21:34:45.343 12820-12820/? E/XmlParser: startElement mResult:1024
2018-10-30 21:34:45.343 12820-12820/? E/XmlParser: startElement mResult:2097152
2018-10-30 21:34:45.351 408-2015/? E/ion: set flags ioctrl failed!
2018-10-30 21:34:45.439 12706-12706/paixao.com.findingdawae E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: paixao.com.findingdawae, PID: 12706
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {paixao.com.findingdawae/paixao.com.findingdawae.UpgradeClickActvity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:3952)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3918)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3860)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1588)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(AccessibleObject.java:133)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:119)
        at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.PreJava9ReflectionAccessor.makeAccessible(PreJava9ReflectionAccessor.java:31)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:103)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:85)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:101)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter$1.create(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:48)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
2018-10-30 21:34:45.439 12706-12706/paixao.com.findingdawae E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:56)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
        at paixao.com.findingdawae.UpgradeClickActvity.saveData(UpgradeClickActvity.java:133)
        at paixao.com.findingdawae.UpgradeClickActvity.onPause(UpgradeClickActvity.java:87)
        at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7071)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1335)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:3941)
            ... 11 more
2018-10-30 21:34:45.443 1218-4703/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
2018-10-30 21:34:45.518 554-830/? E/logserver: imonitor_add_dynamic_path, path:/data/system/dropbox/data_app_crash@1540935285455.txt.gz
2018-10-30 21:34:45.635 1218-6950/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
2018-10-30 21:34:45.678 1020-12064/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=40, operation=LogOperation
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=Log from CONTEXT_MANAGER dropped because of storage full, resolution=null}]
        at oxj.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):72)
        at xey.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):27)
        at bdrz.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):2)
        at qjt.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):35)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at qpu.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
2018-10-30 21:34:45.685 1020-12064/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=40, operation=LogOperation
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=Log from LB_COUNTERS dropped because of storage full, resolution=null}]
        at oxj.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):72)
        at xey.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):27)
        at bdrz.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):2)
        at qjt.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):35)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at qpu.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
2018-10-30 21:34:45.720 1020-12064/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=40, operation=LogOperation
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=Log from CONTEXT_MANAGER dropped because of storage full, resolution=null}]
        at oxj.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):72)
        at xey.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):27)
        at bdrz.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):2)
        at qjt.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):35)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at qpu.run(:com.google.android.gms@14366021@14.3.66 (040408-213742215))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
```

Comment: please include your code not image.

Comment: and your error stacktrace.

Comment: Done @LeoPelozo

Comment: Done @want2learn

Answer (score 0):

Add no-args constructor to your `UpgradesClick` class

```
public UpgradesClick() {

}
```